# How to plot individual points without curve in python?

Tags: python, plot, curve, linestyle

I want to plot individual data points with error bars on a plot, but I don't want to have the curve. How can I do this? Are there some 'invisible' line style or can I set the line style colourless (but the marker still has to be visible)?

So this is the graph I have right now:

```
plt.errorbar(x5,y5,yerr=error5, fmt='o')
plt.errorbar(x3,y3,yerr=error3, fmt='o')

plt.plot(x3_true,y3_true, 'r--', label=(r'$\lambda = 0.3$'))
plot(x5_true, y5_true, 'b--', label=(r'$\lambda = 0.5$'))

plt.plot(x5,y5, linestyle=':', marker='o', color='red') #this is the 'ideal' curve that I want to add
plt.plot(x3,y3, linestyle=':', marker='o', color='red')
```

[image: my graph]

I want to keep the two dashed curve but I don't want the two dotted curve. How can I do this? And how can I change the color of the markers so I can have red points for the red curve, blue points for the blue curve?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `scatter`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively:

```
plt.plot(x, y, 's')
```

[image]

EDIT: If you want error bars you can do:

```
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=err, fmt='o')
```

[image]

Comment: sorry for missing some key points. I want the data points to have error bars, so I use plt.errorbar, but I don't want to have the curve associated with the data points with error bar as I will add another smooth curve myself.

Comment: with `plot.errorbar` you can do: `plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=err, fmt='o')`

Comment: I just posted the code. What have I done wrong? I still have the dotted curve with the data points.

Comment: You are doing, `plt.plot(x3,y3, linestyle=':', marker='o', color='red')`, you don't need this, if you already used `errorbar`